# Optimum minimum number of instances in weka's j48

Tags: decision-trees, weka

There is a parameter named `minnumobj` in the options of the `j48` tree algorithm in `weka`. This parameter indicates the minimum number of participants to be in a leaf. Does this parameter have an optimum value regarding the instances or attributes? Or should I set the value that achieves the highest classification success? For example, I have 6500 instances and 9 attributes and I got highest success when `minnumobj=100`.

Answer (score 2):

If there were an optimum in terms of number of instances or attributes, then that would be set in the program.  No, such a parameter generally has an optimum that depends on the data itself, and needs to be tuned to get optimal performance.